# How to embed SVG files in html?

Tags: html, svg

I know how to embed them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819921/how-to-embed-svg-in-html but that creates another problem for me. Whenever I open the page with that SVG element in it, the SVG file is not being rendered, but downloaded - what's causing it?

I've tried `iframe`, `object` and `img` approaches - `img` doesn't show anything while iframe and object force the file to be downloaded. Does it need some server configuration?

Comment: does embeding that work on localhost? can you show the html page code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to embed it in the HTML, use the `svg` tag directly (option 6 in the post you linked to). But the other options shouldn't cause it to be downloaded. Check the headers on the response from the server; a [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) header might cause that.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SVG being served from localhost?  If not, check that your webserver is serving the SVG file with the correct MIME type.  The `Content-type` response header should be `image/svg+xml`.  You can check this in the Net/Network tab of your browser dev tools.